# Making sense of why 乙嫁語り is translated as "A Bride's Story"

Tags: translation

While browsing reddit I came across the expression 乙嫁語り and its translation as *A Bride's story*.

Now I'm not really far into my kanji studies (maybe a 400-500 characters in), but since I recognized the 語 and the 嫁, I was a bit confused how one can translate this as *A Bride's story*. If I'm not mistaken this should be read as *Otoyomegatari* (Googleing the name of the Manga confirms this).

1. What exactly is the 乙 doing here? *Otoyome* can be translated as [*younger brothers wife*](https://jisho.org/search/otoyome), although then its written as 弟嫁 and not as 乙嫁. And as far as I understand the kanji 乙 itself means something along the lines of　[the latter, duplicate, strange, witty](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B9%99%20%23kanji), which doesn't seem to be related to the title at all.
2. When talking about the word *tale* I immediately think about the word 物語, so reading 語り confused me a bit since according to [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%8A) it means something along the lines of *talk, narration, topic* --- so a word that would maybe used to describe a conversation and less a story/tale.

So can somebody maybe explain to me how we get to the translation *A Bride's story*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. おと (弟 or 乙 in kanji) is an archaic prefix meaning "younger/youngest (in a family, regardless of sex)" or "little lovely". From a 古語辞典:

   > #### [おと－ 【弟・乙】](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B9%99)
   >
   > 接頭語
   >   ①〔人を表す語または人名に付けて〕年下の。末の。「兄（え）宇迦斯（うかし）・弟宇迦斯」。
   >   ②〔人を表す語または人名に付けて〕美しい。愛する。年若い。かわいい。「弟橘比売命（たちばなひめのみこと）」

   I don't know how common 乙嫁 was in real archaic Japanese, but the [official site](https://www.enterbrain.co.jp/pickup/2009/otoyomegatari/) clearly says 乙嫁 in this manga means "beautiful bride". This also means even an average native speaker does not know what 乙嫁 means. As an aside, you can read about a recent derivative meaning of 乙 [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1416/5010).
2. The modern primary meaning of 語り is indeed "narration" (as in a documentary film), but since it's used with an unfamiliar archaic word here, I take it as a nominalized version of 語る (i.e., "talking"). But 物語 is etymologically just 語り preceded by 物, so you can take it simply as a variant of 物語, too.

So possible literal translations of 乙嫁語り would be "Story of a Beautiful Bride" or "Talking about a Beautiful Bride".